# Cannot connect to websocket by unicorn and uwsgi

Tags: django, websocket

I have tried the following 6 methods to start my `django` project.

```
1. command=python3 manage.py
2. command=daphne myproject.asgi:application -b 0.0.0.0 -p 778
3. command=uwsgi --ini /root/uwsgi.ini
4. command=uvicorn myproject.asgi:application --workers 4 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 778  
5. command=gunicorn myproject.wsgi --workers 2  --bind 0.0.0.0:778
6. command=gunicorn myproject.asgi:application -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -b 0.0.0.0:778
```

However, only the **first two** methods are able to connect to websocket. Unfortunately, there is not too much error details left in my client(Only know the error code is `1006`). Anyone knows why I cannot connect?

Comment: Its better to provide more details, what kind of webserver you are using, is it django's development server?

Comment: Error code error 1006" is one of the issues that users get as a result of the incorrect or failed installation or uninstallation of software.

Comment: @Jisson My webserver is Nginx. The software here is `uvicorn`, `daphne`, and `gunicorn`, all of them are installed by `pip install`

Comment: its better to add the important part of nginx conf,   gunicorn service file in the question

Comment: @Jisson You mean it, I have successfully work it out by install `uvicorn[standard]`